# How to find the Extensions used in PHP Project?

Tags: php

When publish PHP project to server,maybe this server not support some extensions but my project required, so I want to find all extionsions my project used.

Like...

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "ext-gd": "*"
 }
```

is there some Tools or Commands support?

```
###For Example
    //filename is exp.php
    class exp{
        private $array = ['a'=>'b'];
        private $conn = mysql_connect("....");
    }
    //tool or command result 
    require >=PHP5.4,ext-mysql,


    //filename is exp.php
    namespace com\core\exp
    class exp{
        private $array = array('a'=>'b');
        private $conn = new mysqli("....");
    }
    //tool or command result 
    require >=PHP5.3,ext-mysqli
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to load a PHP extension is to include it in your php.ini configuration file. Please note that many extensions are already present in your php.ini and that you only need to remove the semicolon to activate them.

```
;extension=php_extname.dll
```

change like this

```
extension=php_extname.dll
```

However, some web servers are confusing because they do not use the php.ini located alongside your PHP executable. To find out where your actual php.ini resides, look for its path in phpinfo():

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\WINDOWS

Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files\PHP\5.2\php.ini
```

After activating an extension, save php.ini, restart the web server and check phpinfo() again. The new extension should now have its own section.

for example:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`php -m` : will give all the modules list

`php -i` : will give more detailed information about current configuration.